# dyld: Library not loaded: But Library seems entirely unrelated

Tags: linker, dyld, darwin, otool

I have an interesting issue: I have a C++ project (built with CMake/make) and probably some dependency I had compiled from source had *their* dependency updated via `brew upgrade`. Now, when I `make`, I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/x265/lib/libx265.179.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

However, the application does not use ffmpeg, libavcodec or similar directly. It does use OpenCV (which may link against those, I don't know), and the Spinnaker SDK for FLIR cameras (which depends on `libavcodec`).

**Question**: What command line tools can I use, to recursively search through the linked libraries for a binary to find the offending (missing) library? I ran `otool -L` on my binary, but it does not directly link against the offending libs.

Comment: I have found that reinstallint/recompiling libraries which depend on any other libraries which were upgraded usually solves the problem. That does not answer the question of how to pinpoint the exact location of the problem.